# Visual Studio weirdness

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, scramble

I have no one else to count unless this fantastic community, I know this is a non-programmer question but I can't figure it out why this is happening.

To a client I developed, **using [960.GS](http://960.GS)** a layout with a simple login user page / choose product / register products using .NET (ASP.NET 3.5) and all was ok, they agreed and I started ...

I then imported the **HTML files** I did and started to replace input with asp:TextBox's and the button into an asp:Button, really simple/basic stuff, but soon I click "View in Browser" I got my code **all scrambled**!

even if I see a XHTML 1.1 Strict Validated code, and CSS 2.1 Validate code

to try to get what's wrong, I put the ASPX file aside and open only the HTML page.

results are **very different**:

Opening directly in Firefox, with no web server:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-11-22_1116.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-11-22_1116.png)

if I run the same page (exactly the same code) [**HTML page**, no ASP.NET page] through **Cassini (Visual Studio Web Server)** it shows .. ohh well...

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-11-22_1117.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-11-22_1117.png)

as well if I run that html page from **IIS 7.5**

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-11-22_1129.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-11-22_1129.png)

> **all 3 files above are the same page**, being run through 2 different servers Cassini, IIS and the normal HTML render from Firefox.

using Firebug, all css loads well

screen cast: http://bit.ly/7ZBkuh (20 sec)

Does anyone have any idea for this behavior?

> All help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a css overflow problem. Are there any differences between the resultant markup/css from the browser (not the source file in the url bar) - eg, by comparing the "View page source" result? I suspect there will be. And i suspect that it's css related not markup.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to run a diffing tool against your original HTML file and the output produced by your ASPX page.  It will definitely be expected to see some differences, but it might still help you highlight what's going wrong.

Comment: -1 the example in my question is showing HTML pages, no ASPX related! The objective is to work with the ASP.NET but as for test I show in all 3 files a html extension and I wrote "but if I run the same page (exactly the same code)..."

Comment: You still want to run a diff off the source that the browser has with the raw html file - you're right that there shouldn't be a difference but you can't assume that there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess, but perhaps the CSS styles that you *are* seeing in the ASP.NET-hosted pages are defined in the page, and the CSS styles that you *are not* seeing are defined in a separate CSS file?

If that is indeed the case, then the problem could be due to the way you have configured ASP.NET authentication in `web.config`. It may be serving up the HTML file but blocking the CSS file.